# Is there a built-in command in Julia Pkg to switch the selected environment?

Tags: julia, environment

The Julia Pkg documentation tells how to initiate an environment (`$ activate $ENV-NAME`), but it probably lacks the handy command to switch to the already created special environment. Also, I'm having trouble finding a  command that shows all already created environments on the list, hence, if I have forgotten the names of the environments previously created, I need to do a manual search through the Julia-related folders...

So far, the verbatim `help` command in Julia REPL provides a poor description and so does the related Pkg-documentation webpage.

Another possible general answer to this predicament is to start using the Playground.jl module, which was recommended here on [Medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/set-up-virtual-environment-in-julia-with-playground-jl-7ab02a0df751):

However, the direct download attempt with Pkg repeatedly fails since the Pkg isn't able to find the package in the suggested GH project.

Thanks beforehand for any recommendations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In package manager prompt just type `activate @` and press `tab`-key. The REPLs autocomplete will show you the possible environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Your prompt has led to the resolution of the issue. 
Probably one thing to be emphasized is that the `activate @ ` command **should** contain _single space_ in the end - otherwise the only environment that appears after pressing tab is the default one (`@v1.4`) . 

Another, more concise way to do it is to press `tab` after just typing `activate ` (also with single space) - this yields the list of existing environments. 

(Julia is installed for the single User, not on the system level - if it makes any difference).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Mac or Linux
you can run this shell command to find all the "enviroment"

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/ssiew/juliascript

bash-3.2$ find . -name Project.toml
./Luxordir/Project.toml
./symata/Project.toml
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'm on Windows, sorry for not noting that above, but this command still works in Bash Shell, only the starting folder should be changed to AppData or so, of course, this not necessarily yields the paths to environments alone, but their names and paths are still obvious from the response.